# select option dropdown onchange update variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

Here is my dilemma.  A multi-select drop-down displays pre-selected options.  When the user makes any changes, I'm running some code in the PHP action file (called through a submit button).  I'm trying to accomplish this using a flag and updating the flag in the onchange event of "select option".  The rest is working fine.  I just wanted to execute the queries in action file only when the user changed selections in drop down rather than every time the form is submitted. However I'm unable to pass the flag successfully.  I know I'm missing something basic and have spent two days looking at it.  Any help is appreciated.

The relevant code is pasted below:

```
//Initialize flag

<?php
...
 $multi_prog_change_flag = '0';  
...
?>

//Hidden Form Element

<form action="update_u.php" method="post" id="cForm" name="cForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" autocomplete="off">
...
<?php echo '<input type="hidden" id="email"   value="'.$email.'">    ';?>
<?php echo '<input type="hidden" id="multiprogchangeflag" name="multiprogchangeflag"  value="'.$multi_prog_change_flag.'">    ';?>
...


// Drop-down Element where update is triggered

<tr id="odd">
<td><select id="programName" name="programName[]" onchange="updateflag();>" multiple="multiple" size=10>
..
<option name="drop1" value ="<?php echo $data['Program_Id'] ?>"  <?php if ($data[curr_prog] == '1')  echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>> <?php echo $data['Program_Name'];?></option>
..
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="pNames"   name="pNames" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

// Function to update flag 

function updateflag() {
    <document.getElementById("multiprogchangeflag").value = "1";
}

// update_u.php PHP Action File

$multi_prog_flag=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['multiprogchangeflag']);

if ($multi_prog_flag == '1'){
    $multi_prog_delete_query=mysql_query("UPDATE multi_prog_access SET is_act = '0', Updated_by = '$updatedby', update_timestamp = NOW() WHERE user_id = '$useid'");

    $count = count($multi_prog_names); 

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $multi_prog_ID=$multi_prog_names[$i];
        $multi_prog_update_query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO multi_prog_access (user_id, Prog_id, created_by, is_act, Update_timestamp) VALUES ('$ids','$multi_prog_ID', '$updatedby', '1', NOW())"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you edit your question.  You have non code formatted as code.

Comment: Get the old value and the new value then compare if they match. If they don't match, that means the user has changed the value. Go ahead and update your flag.

Comment: where is the point? your goal is not elementary. try split the issue in HTML+js on one hand and PHP on the other.

Comment: sorry guys, this is my first post - if i haven't adhered to any protocols, i apologize in advance...